# HasMany, BelongsTo for price comparision problem

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I want to make a price comparison section on my site. Now I really have trouble understanding the relationships between a Product, a Shop and a Price.

A Product is available in multiple Shops, who each have a Price.

So I have a table Products, a table Shops and a table Prices, in Prices I store the product_id, the shop_id and the price

Just to check, I would define it like this:

```
Product hasManyAndBelongsTo Shop
Shop hasManyAndBelongsTo Product
Price belongsTo Shop
Price belongsTo Product
```

But I feel this is not correct, is anyone able to give me the right connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd define it like this:

```
Product hasAndBelongsToMany Shop with Price
Shop hasAndBelongsToMany Product with Price
```

check the "[with](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM)" attribute when declaring a HABTM relation. Your modeling is ok

Cheers