# CakePHP defining additional fields in HABTM/ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: cakephp, model, relational-database, has-and-belongs-to-many

Basically I would like to recreate this in CakePHP:

[Many to many relationships with additional data on the relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755591/many-to-many-relationships-with-additional-data-on-the-relationship)

or in other words, my intermediary table to have extra fields defining the type of relationship.

How do I set this up in CakePHP?

You can use as example:

```
model company:
    id
    name
    person_id
model person:
    id
    name
model company_person:
    company_id
    person_id
    position
```

thanx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815254/hasmany-belongsto-for-price-comparision-problem/6815893#6815893

Comment: I may not have been clear in the question, but I am interested in that `position` field specifically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you want to have additional data in HABTM, use 2 hasMany relationships instead. So if A HABTM B, then set it up as: A hasMany A_B, B hasMany A_B, A_B belongsTo A, A_B belongsTo B. AFAIK, Cake support for HABTM is not very flexible.

Comment: it's not really weird though :P In HABTM, the middle table only serves as the connection. But when you add data to it, it has certain meaning, and can be "promoted" to a Model. In your case, company_person actually is an employments table in disguise. So, you can, and should, rename the table to employments (or something like that).

Answer (score 1):

```
class Person extends AppModel {
    ...
    $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Company', array('with' => 'CompanyPerson'));
    ....
}
```

Comment: This is the basic way that HABTM is setup. However, I am interested If I have to do anything specific for the POSITION field to work and be read/written

Comment: Mh iirc you just needed to specify the table with "with" keyword (instead of letting cakephp use automatic association) and you could get the extra data in the table. But after googling a bit I found this: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1650/hasMany-through-The-Join-Model . So maybe I was wrong :p